# How to send a mail in php to Gmail?

Tags: php, email, gmail

I try to do contactUs page in my web (Now I work with xampp and netbeans on my localhost)

File `contactUs.php`:

```
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="send_form_email.php">
  <table width="450px">

    <tr>
      <td valign="top">
        <label for="first_name">First Name *</label>
      </td>
      <td valign="top">
        <input  type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30"></input>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td valign="top">
        <label for="last_name">Last Name *</label>
      </td>
      <td valign="top">
        <input  type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30"></input>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td valign="top">
        <label for="email">Email Address *</label>
      </td>
      <td valign="top">
        <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30"></input>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td valign="top">
        <label for="telephone">Telephone Number</label>
      </td>
      <td valign="top">
        <input  type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30"></input>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td valign="top">
        <label for="comments">Comments *</label>
      </td>
      <td valign="top">
        <textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"> </input>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</form>
```

File `send_form_email.php`:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "my@gmail.com";
    $email_subject = "ssss";

    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if (!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');
    }

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required
    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

  if (!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if (!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if (!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if (strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if (strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }

  $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

  function clean_string($string) {
    $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
    return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
  }

  $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
  $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
  $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
  $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
  $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";

  // create email headers
  $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
  'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
  'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

  // send the email
  mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
?>

<!-- include your own success html here -->

Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

<?php
}
?>
```

My problem is that it is not working. I'm filling out the form and do Submit, get the success message, but do not receive an e-mail in my Gmail account.

Is there anything else I need?  I guess I need to define it from where to send the form; define something in file `php.ini` maybe?

Comment: Have you checked “spam” folder @gmail?

Comment: have u configured the send mail in local ?

Comment: The problems might be caused by setting the `From:` header which is different from the server host name. GMail probably throws such messages into spam folder.

Comment: Hi, I check the spam folder, nothing there..

@ColoO How do I configure send mail in local?
I just do what I wrote above (in the php files)

Comment: Did you configure your mail in php??
http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php

Comment: [xampp mail config](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965376/how-to-configure-xampp-to-send-mail-from-localhost)

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure your e-mail in php?

http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php

You can check your configuration with the `phpinfo();` change your php.ini and you can use the information your internet provider provided for outgoing e-mail by adjusting the SMTP options etc (this only works for windows) you could use the information your ISP provided to you for your internet connection.

Second option is using sendmail to send your e-mail so you can use gmail as your smtp server for xampp it's explained here: (sendmail is allready build-in in xampp)
[How to configure XAMPP to send mail from localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965376/how-to-configure-xampp-to-send-mail-from-localhost)

Comment: Hi,
I didn't configure the php.ini.
I need to change to something like this?
SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587

Comment: You need to configure it otherwise it will never work, here is the direct link to the answer wich explains it step by step: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18185233/2032020

Comment: You could also configure php to relay your mail to your internet provider wich works in some cases. I'm from the netherlands and i can use  mail.chello.nl (or something) as my smtp relay. using gmail as smtp server requires you to configure sendmail also

Comment: still not working...  :-(

Comment: Are you using windows or linux distro? Setting the SMTP is only for Windows. you need to use the sendmail_path when you use a linux distro. If that isn't working you need to check your error.log/debug.log that you have defined in your sendmail configuration.

Comment: I'm using win7 64bit.

other question, If I want to move it to a website, do I need all this configuration  or it's only to localhost?
Thanks!

Comment: No you only need to configure it for your localhost (probably) your hosting should have configure this allready for their enviroment

Answer (score 0):

Sending email from your server sometimes cause intermittent problem. If i were you i will use external smtp service suchbas gmail. I created a simple code to test your mail server tonsend email, please see it here: https://github.com/ivankristianto/PHP-Mail-Tester 
You can try a lot of configuration, please see the instructions for more details.

Answer (score -1):

maybe the gmail refuse your request.
because you use the default function mail()

you can use smtp protocol to send email,pop3 to receive email.

Comment: the default mail function should just work google wouldn't deny your request. It's could be it's denied somewhere between the line